# How do you delete a to do from a list that is reversed?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I used *array_reverse* to add newly created to-dos to the top of the list. But now I am having trouble deleting them. When I click the checkbox to delete an item, it will delete the one on the opposite end of the list. Could anyone tell me the best way to reverse the order and have them delete properly? Is array_reverse the best way to accomplish this or is there a better alternative. My two files are below.

index.php

```
<?php
// cookies
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 172800);

session_set_cookie_params(172800);

// array('get milk', 'feed dog');
include 'TaskList.php';


$list = new TaskList('tasks');


if(isset($_POST['task'])) {
  // if post task is set the user submitted a task
  $list->addItem($_POST['task']);
  $list->save();
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  // delete this item from the array
  $keys = $_POST['delete'];
  foreach($keys as $key) {
      array_reverse($list->deleteItem($key));
  }
  $list->save();
 }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
<body>

<h1>To Do List</h1>

<!-- Insert Items -->
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <label for="task">
    Enter task: <input type="text" name="task" id="task" value="" placeholder="Enter Task Here">
  </label>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Add">
</form>

<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach(array_reverse($list->items) as $key => $task): ?>
      <!-- [] tell browser that it's an array and to delete more than one item at a time -->
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $task; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Delete">
</form>

<hr>

<?php var_dump(array_reverse($list->items)) ?>

</body>
</html>
```

TaskList.php

```
<?php


class TaskList {

  var $items;
  var $listname;

  public function __construct($listname){
    session_start();

    $this->listname = $listname;

    if(isset($_SESSION[$this->listname])) {
      $this->items = $_SESSION[$this->listname];
    }
    else {
      $this->items = array();
    }
  }

  public function addItem($item) {
    $this->items[] = $item;
  }

  public function deleteItem($key) {
    unset($this->items[$key]);
  }

  public function save() {
    $_SESSION[$this->listname] = $this->items;
  }

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't change (and keep changing) your data structurally just to display it differently. This is just confusing. You can use a for() loop and go backwards if you want it displayed in reverse. This will preserve your key/value pairs.

Comment: If you're dead set on using `array_reverse()`, you should tell it to preserve keys (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: I must admit, I am somewhat confused: why do you need to modify the list's order when you access the element to be deleted directly via its key?

Comment: Also, can you clarify what you mean by "When I click the checkbox to delete an item, it will delete the one on the opposite end of the list"?

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. I only want how it's displayed to be reversed, so an item added goes to the top of the list as opposed to the bottom. And what I meant by "delete the opposite one" is let's say when I check off the item at the very bottom of the list and click delete, it will instead delete the item at the top.

Answer (score 0):

A *for* loop can be used here to keep the ordering of items in the tasklist by doing a backwards loop.

I added a convenience method in the TaskList class to easily access keys

```
function getKey($key) {
    return $this->items[$key];
}
```

PHP template modified to use *for* loop:

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <?php 
      $count = count($taskList->items) - 1;
      for($key=$count; $key >= 0; $key--) {
        $task = $taskList->getKey($key);
    ?>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="delete[]" value="<?php echo $key ?>">
          <?php echo $task; ?></li>
    <?php  } ?>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Reverse delete

The objective here is to remove the element at the opposite in the array. One way to do this is to get the keys for the array using `array_keys` and then use `array_reverse` on the result to give us a map of the opposite keys.

```
$reverseKeys = array_reverse(array_keys($arr));

// output of print_r($reverseKeys) for an array indexed from 0 to 4
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 0
)
```

Then we can use this map to delete the appropriate element.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    // delete this item from the array
    $keys = $_POST['delete'];
    $reverseKeys = array_reverse(array_keys($arr));

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $list->deleteItem($reverseKeys[$key]);
    }
    $list->save();
}
```

---

Since this question has the `oop` tag, I'm gonna try and focus on giving a more object-oriented approach and how the current design can be improved.

## The design of the `TaskList` object

First, let us take a look at the `TaskList` object's design and see what we can improve.

### Encapsulation

One of the key concept of Object-Oriented programming (*the* most important for some) is that of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In a nutshell, encapsulation means that the inner workings and attributes of an object are hidden from the code that consumes the object. What this means in practice is that an object should have `private` properties and only expose them (some or all) via public accessors.

An accessor can either return a value with no modifications

```
public function getDateOfBirth() {
    return $this->dateOfBirth;
}
```

Or perform some modifications to give more meaning to the data

```
public function getAge() {
    // assuming $dateOfBirth is an instance of DateTime
    $diff = $dateOfBirth->diff(new DateTime());
    return $diff->format('%y');
}
```

Looking at the `TaskList` class, we can convert the attributes `$items` and `$listName` to private members, and create accessors for them.

```
class TaskList {

    private $items = [];
    private $listname = '';

    public function __construct($listname){
        /* ... */
    }

    public function getListName() {
        return $this->listName;
    }

    public function getItems() {
        return $this->items;
    }
}
```

The rest of the class looks good to me; `addItem()`, `deleteItem()` and `save()` are all pretty self-explanatory and well contained. but what about the rest of the code? Looking at the `index.php` file, there are things we can refactor into `TaskList`. The biggest one is the `foreach` loop to perform a bulk delete. The `TaskList` class should be able to perform this action on its own without exposing it's internal structure to the rest of the code.

```
// rename delete to deleteOne
public function deleteOne($key) {
    unset $this->items[$key];
}

public function deleteItems($keys) {
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $this->deleteOne($key);
    }
}

// reverse delete from earlier
public function reverseDeleteItems($keys) {
    $reverseKeys = array_reverse(array_keys($arr));

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $this->deleteOne($reverseKeys[$key]);
    }
}
```

### Responsibility

Antoher important principle often applied in Object-Oriented programming is that of [Single Responsability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Without going into too much detail, the Single Responsability Principle (SRP) states that an object should only take care of its own data/processes, and nothing outside of that scope. Here, the responsibility of `TaskList` is to maintain a list of Tasks. However, it is also handling the php session in it's constructor, which falls outside of its responsibility.

index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start()
    /* ... */
```

TaskList.php:

```
class TaskList {
    /* ... */
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->listname = $name;

        if(isset($_SESSION[$this->listname])) {
            $this->items = $_SESSION[$this->listname];
        }
        else {
            $this->items = array();
        }
    }
```

---

#### Further Improvement

There should be enough information above to help you solve your problem, but I'd like to take the opportunity to offer some suggestions.

First, the `$items` is a simple array, which works well now, but may cause problems in the future. An array could contain anything really, and it may not be in the right format. What you can do instead is create a `Task` class, and have each element of `Item` instantiate it. That way validating that each task has the appropriate elements becomes very easy and it also scales better.

```
class Task {

    private $name;
    private $value;
    private $priority;  // value from 0 to 9
    private $createdAt;
    private $updatedAt;

    public function __construct($name, $value, $priority = 5) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->priority = $priority;

        $now = new DateTime();
        $this->createdAt = $now;
        $this->updatedAt = $now;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->updatedAt = new DateTime();
    }

    public function getPriority() {
        return $this->priority;
    }

    public function toArray() {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'value' => $this->value,
            'priority' => $this->priority,
            'createdAt' => $this->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'updatedAt' => $this->updatedAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        ];
    }
}
```

This gives you the possibility to modify the `add` function like so

```
public function addItem($name, $value, $priority = null) {
    // if items must be unique
    if(array_key_exists($name, $this->items)) {
        throw new Exception('An item with the same name already exists');
    }

    $this->items[$name] = new Task($name, $value, $priority);
}
```

As you can see, I can now have a lot more information about each `Task` with minimal modifications to the `TaskList` class.

Additionally, you can improve `TaskList` even more by refactoring the saving mechanism in a `TaskListRepository` that will take care of getting instances of `TaskList` and persisting them to whatever system you prefer (MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB, .txt files, session variables).

```
class TaskListRepository {

    public function save($list) {
        /* store list */
    }

    public function getOne($name) {
        /* fetch instance of a TaskList */
        return $taskList;
    }
}
```

You can now modify the `index.php` like so

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $taskListRepo = new TaskListRepository();
    $taskList = $taskListRepo->getOne('myList');

    $taskList->addOne('groceries', 'I need to pick up the groceries');
    $taskListRepo->save($taskList);
```